# Drawing app : turn pixels to grayscale or erase them

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a drawing app which consists of a container with a background image in grayscale and over it, there's another image (the same but not in grayscale).
When I draw on my image, I would to erase where I drawn or turn in grayscale (to reproduce the image in background).
How can I achieve that ?
Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #wrapper {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: url('elephant-nb-400.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
            var canvas = document.querySelector("#wrapper canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.setAttribute("src", "elephant-400.jpg");
            image.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 600, 400);
            };

            var positionsX = new Array();
            var positionsY = new Array();
            var movements = new Array();
            var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var data = imageData.data;
            var isErasing; 

            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
                 var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                 var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                 isErasing = true;
                 addPositions(mouseX, mouseY);
                 draw();
            });

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                if(isErasing) {
                    addPositions(mouseX, mouseY, true);
                    draw();
                }
            });

            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
                isErasing = false;
            });

            var addPositions = function(x, y, isMoving) {
                positionsX.push(x);
                positionsY.push(y);
                movements.push(isMoving);
            }

            var draw = function(){
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

                for(var i=0; i < positionsX.length; i++) {  
                  context.beginPath();
                  if(movements[i] && i){

                   }else{

                   }
                   context.lineTo(positionsX[i], positionsY[i]);
                   context.closePath();
                   context.stroke();
                }
              }

        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.
You need to get the image data : `var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
In function draw(), you need to add : `context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, positionsX[i]-1, positionsY[i], 20, 20);` after `context.moveTo(positionsX[i-1], positionsY[i-1]);`and `context.moveTo(positionsX[i]-1, positionsY[i]);`